# How do I add space inside \textrm{}?

Tags: spacing

I googled this, but couldn't find an answer.

How do I add space inside \textrm{}?

e.g. I want to get "Hello_____World", but what I get is "Hello_World" when I type in \textrm{Hello_____World}. Please note that _ is there just to show spacing size.

Thanks in advance.

p.s. The question is inside \textrm{}. \, \quad, \hspace, etc. don't work inside \textrm{}.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! TeX reads consecutive space characters as a single space token. You need to either `Hello\ \ \ world` or `Hello\hspace{1cm}world`.

Comment: If I may add a piece of unsolicited advice, don’t try to learn the basics of LaTeX just by “googling” or by asking “how-to” questions on the Internet: it’s impossible to learn anything even moderately complex in that way, and LaTeX is way more than moderately complex!  That being said, welcome to TeX.SX again!

Comment: If I do \textrm{Hello\ \ \ world}, what I get is "Hello\ \ \ world". Similarly, if I do \textrm{Hello\hspace{1cm}world}, I get "Hello\hspace{1cm}world". What I want is "Hello     World". Outside \textrm, \ or \hspace works for sure, but I'm asking for inside \textrm{}. BTW, I've been using LaTex for almost 10 years, so I'm not a beginner.

Comment: @S.J. `\textrm` should just change to the roman typeface of your document, so it shouldn't affect anything. However, the only way to get `Hello\ \ \ world` print `Hello\ \ \ world` is if **a)** you're in verbatim mode or **b)** `\textrm` was redefined to make some kind of verbatim mode. And in verbatim mode rules stop applying :-) Please show us a compilable example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik  Thank you for the response. I'm doing this in MathJax, so I think this may be the culprit. What I did was \begin{equation} \textrm{a. \ \ \ Hello World} \end{equation} and I got "a. \ \ \ Hello World".

Comment: @S.J. MathJax is not TeX, so rules don't apply either :-) Using `\mathrm` instead of `\textrm` seems to work on https://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about MathJax.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Sorry for asking in the wrong forum. Please close this question.